# POST Response Best Practice - Should I return an Entity or a Server Side Redirect?

Tags: java, redirect, post, response, httpresponse

Basically exactly what the title says.  I have an app that lets users update info on a database.  Within the code, I've set up the response to return a message on a success:

```
public Response updatePerson(@PathParam("id") int id, @FormParam("name") String name) throws Exception {

   Profile profile = new Profile(id, name)
   manager.updateProfile(id, person);
   return Response.status(201).entity("Profile updated.").build();
```

However, I would also like to do a redirect, which can be done like so:

```
public Response updatePerson(@PathParam("id") int id, @FormParam("name") String name) throws Exception {

   Person person = new Person(id, name)
   manager.updatePerson(id, person);
   return Response.seeOther(new URI("/home")).build()
```

My question is twofold:

1. What is the best practice when returning a response for POST methods?  Should there be a response body confirming that the POST was successful, or is the code enough for it?
2. Is there any way to combine the two operations so the entity on the response body is returned, while also performing the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the response code 200 upon success. You can return a response body but it depends on what the client requires or expects after the update. If you want to do a redirect the response code 301 can be used with the content 'Location: http://www.example.org/index.asp'. But if you return 301 it does not mean the request was correctly. At the redirected URL you can return 201 then indicating it was correct.

For more information see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

**Note:** Normaly if you want to do an update the `PUT` HTTP request is used. `POST` is mostly used for creation, and `GET` for retrieval of data.